# Is it possible to adjust notification sound volume dynamically in Android O and above?

Tags: android

I fully understand since Android O and above, there's no easy way to customize notification sound through app's code.

The common way to do so, is to invoke `Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`

```
private void showNotificationSoundListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat(Preference preference) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getContext().getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, com.yocto.wenote.reminder.Utils.createNotificationChannel());
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            trackEvent("showNotificationSoundListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat", "fatal", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like following

### [image]

However, I notice some apps in the market, do provide way to adjust notification sound volume dynamically.

[image]

May I know, what is the way to achieve so?

Comment: What do you mean about "Dynamically"? Just increase/decrease its volume?

Comment: You can adjust the volume via app, and such volume adjustment only specifically targetting this app, not entire device

Comment: Could you introduce a program which does this?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Im wondering if i answered your question correctly?

Comment: @aminography https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.northpark.drinkwater&hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is merely a hack, a way to get it to do so, and it will achieve your required behavior. In my application, targeting API 26; i have implemented a sound and vibration customization but manually.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Channel1");

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    // Vibrations

    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(new long[] {200,300,500,100,100}, 1));

    //Sound 

    Intent soundIntent = new Intent(this, PlaySound.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("ACTION_START_PLAYBACK");
    serviceIntent.putExtra("UriSound", soundUri.toString());
    context.startForegroundService(soundIntent);

    // if notification is outted, just delete notification; thus delete intent

    Intent outNotification = new Intent(context, PlaySound.class);
    deleteIntent.setAction("ACTION_STOP_PLAYBACK");
    PendingIntent pendingOutNotification =
            PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, outNotification, 0);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingOutNotification);

} else {

    builder.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    builder.setSound(uri);

}

notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

In your `PlaySound.class extend service`, Play your sound on a `media player`, and control volume or the particular sound based on the `intent` of that particular `channel`...

Target the volume or the uri based on the users input from the slider, and then send via `intent` or save it in a key-value pair using `sharedpreference`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by following steps
Check for appropriate permission

```
isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()
```

returns boolean and is a part of NotificationManager. 
It is required Android N onwards as it can mend "do not disturb"
If not provided ask for the permission explicitly

```
Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS
```

set up AudioManager in your activity
create a custom view with slider to fetch an int between *getStreamMinVolume(5)* and *getStreamMaxVolume(5)*

then set desired volume with

```
setStreamVolume(5, yourdesiredvalue in int , 0)
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the magic `5` is an id of `AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION`